# how to connect the data from backend to frontend using links in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to access the data from a backend file by using a link in frontend.

Find the code below :

```
     $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->render('hello');
    } else {
        $model->password = '';

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

In the above code instead of hello, I need to pass to farmers page which is in the following location "C:\xampp\htdocs\f_project_yii\backend\views\farmer".

Comment: you have a controller/action in backend for the farmer  page ?

Comment: whats your project path?

Answer (score 1):

One of solution to set absolute path to view like this

```
$model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->render('/farmer');
    } else {
        $model->password = '';

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are use a

```
$this->render('hello');
```

You must to have a
./protected/views/[Controller name in lowcase]/hello.php file